# React Big Calendar Time Change wrong offset

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-big-calendar

I'm using React Big Calendar week's view. The default locale is en-US and this one I'm using currently and would like to still use it. Also I'm staying in +1 timezone. 
When I'm fetching some calendar data from API all data I get is given in UTC. What I find strange is that when time change occurs (week: 29.03 - 4.04) 3:00 AM is shown twice. Also which is even stranger all my events are moved lower by one hour. For example, before time change from API I'm getting event starting at 4AM UTC so it is correctly shown as 5AM in calendar (due to my +1 timezone). After time change I'm getting 4AM UTC but it is shown as 6AM UTC. 
I'm not sure if it is deliberately that way but I would like to have it shown exactly the same (ie. 5AM before and after time change).

Thank you for helping.

I've imported localizer in that way:

```
import { Calendar as BigCalendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

<BigCalendar ... localizer={localizer} ... />
```

Comment: have you set localizer in a right way ??

Comment: Hi, I believe so but I added that info about the way I import it to the content of the question

Comment: I guess you're not setting `moment` correctly. Please take a loot at this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/13kqjp5o43) example.

Comment: Not sure but this imports are for the older version of React Big Calendar

Comment: Di you found any solutions for this. I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The (0.36.0) latest version of RBC has full timezone support now, when using either the `momentLocalizer` or the new `luxonLocalizer`. Doc site isn't up to date yet, but if you run the 'examples' locally you'll find all the info.

The issue of seeing 3AM twice is that date is the beginning of Daylight Savings for your timezone.